# How to get filenames from remote-equipment?

Tags: python-3.x, remote-access

How to get filenames from remote-equipment. For example, there are some pictures in the D drive of spectrum folder "Image", and I want to know the filename of these pictures, how can I do ?

I know how to get filenames from my computer with below codes, but when the files are in remote-equipment, the os.walk seems not workable. Is any method for this ? Thanks in Advance.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("D:\\Image"):
    for filename,x in zip(filenames,range(0,999)):
        if filename.endswith(".png"):
            print(filename)
```